# How to access nested JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, object

Let say I have json data like

```
data = {"id":1,
        "name":"abc",
        "address": {"streetName":"cde",
                    "streetId":2
                    }
        }
```

Now I am getting fields to be accessed from this json data like : `fields = ["id", "name", "address.streetName"]`

How could I access third field (`address.streetName`) from given json data in most efficient way?
`data.fields[2]` doesn't work

One possibility is I construct `data[address][streetName]` string using a for loop and do eval of that but is there any efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Whats wrong with data.address.streetName ?

Comment: I am getting address.streetName as a variable from somewhere. I mean someone is passing me x where x = "address.streetName"

Comment: Hmm, in that case, you'd have to use `eval`, which is not exactly ideal!

To use eval:

`var your_variable = eval("data." + x);`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

To be honest, I can't understand your problem. JSON is already structured out, why do you need to change the structure?

In you case, I would access it as follows:

```
data.address.streetName;
```

If, by any chance, what you want is to *traverse* the data, you would need:

```
function traverse_it(obj){
    for(var prop in obj){
        if(typeof obj[prop]=='object'){
            // object
            traverse_it(obj[prop[i]]);
        }else{
            // something else
            alert('The value of '+prop+' is '+obj[prop]+'.');
        }
    }
}

traverse_it(data);
```

---

**Update**

After reading below, what this user needs seems more obvious. Given property names as a string, s/he wants to access the object.

```
function findProp(obj, prop, defval){
    if (typeof defval == 'undefined') defval = null;
    prop = prop.split('.');
    for (var i = 0; i < prop.length; i++) {
        if(typeof obj[prop[i]] == 'undefined')
            return defval;
        obj = obj[prop[i]];
    }
    return obj;
}

var data = {"id":1,"name":"abc","address":{"streetName":"cde","streetId":2}};
var props = 'address.streetName';
alert('The value of ' + props + ' is ' + findProp(data, props));
```

Comment: +1 I think you have got `data.address.streetName` right, that is what he is looking for probably though his question isn't clear.

Comment: Hmm I will explain it again: address.streetName is a variable coming to me. I have data in json format with me. The situation is like I have data in JSON format and someone is passing "address.streetName" to me and the problem is how should I access value for this key from data

Comment: Yes I thinks its the most efficient solution of this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Be sure to mark the answer that helped you out as the 'right answer'.

Comment: Line 5 should be `obj = obj[prop[i]]`. Also remember to try-catch errors if property string cannot be found in object. Otherwise an excellent answer. +1

Comment: @Christian Could you please give me some solution for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52039222/how-to-implement-hierarchical-multilevel-datatable-in-javascript?noredirect=1#comment91031196_52039222

Answer (score 24):

If you use [lodash](https://lodash.com)(a very popular utility library), you can use [`_.get()`](https://lodash.com/docs#get).

e.g.

```
var data = {
  "id":1,
  "name": "abc",
  "address": {
    "streetName": "cde",
    "streetId":2
  }
}
_.get(data, 'address.streetName');
// 'cde'
_.get(data, ['address', 'streetName']);
// 'cde'
```

If it involves an array, you can use string path like `'address[0].streetName'` as well.

e.g.

```
var data = {
  "id":1,
  "name": "abc",
  "addresses": [
    {
      "streetName": "cde",
      "streetId": 2
    },
    {
      "streetName": "xyz",
      "streetId": 102
    },
  ]
}
_.get(data, 'addresses[0].streetName');
// cde
_.get(data, [address, 1, streetName]);
// xyz
```

Internally, it uses `toPath()` function to convert string path (e.g. `address.streetName`) into an array (e.g. `['address', 'streetName']`), and then uses a function to access the data at the given path within the object.

Other similar utility functions include `_.set()` and `_.has()`. Check them out.

Comment: lodash its pretty straight forward to do this.

Comment: @Brian Park your answer made my day man !. Nice stuff. Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

Long story short, you can use the array notation `object[property]` instead of `object.property`; this is specially useful when the keys contains special characters:

```
var data = {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "abc",
    "address": {
        "streetName": "cde",
        "streetId": 2
    }
}

data.address.streetName;              // (1) dot notation
data["address"]["streetName"];        // (2) array notation
var field = "streetName";
data["address"][field];               // (3) variable inside array notation
var fields = "address.streetName".split(".");
data[fields[0]][fields[1]];           // (4) specific to your question
```

You can use the `typeof` operator to check whether a property exists or not before using it:

```
typeof data["address"]["streetName"]; // returns "string"
typeof data["address"]["foobarblah"]; // returns "undefined"
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `data` variable doesn't have a `fields` property, and that's why `data.fields[2]` doesn't work. I think what you're trying to do there is `data[fields[2]]`, which would work for a simple object, but you can't index into a complex object like that.

Comment: yes correct so is there any efficient way to access nested data compare to following :  col = "address.streetName" //key
exp = "x" // data;
col = col.split(".")
for(var i=0; i<col.length; i++)
    exp+='["' + col[i] + '"]';
eval(exp)

Answer (score 2):

you can access it this way `data.address.streetName`

Comment: Yes but I am getting key in string format ...I mean someone is passing me "address.streetName"

Comment: can't you just loop through your records and do a `if address.streetname == x`

Answer (score 2):

I did it like this:

```
var data = {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "abc",
    "addresses": [{
        "streetName": "cde",
        "streetId": 2
    }, {
        "streetName": "xyz",
        "streetId": 102
    }, ]
}

data2 = data["addresses"]
for (let i in data2) {
    console.log(data2[i]["streetName"]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**JavaScript:**

```
function getProperty(json, path) {
    var tokens = path.split(".");
    var obj = json;
    for (var i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
        obj = obj[tokens[i]];
    }
    return obj;
}

var data = {
    id: 1,
    name: "abc",
    address: {
        streetName: "cde",
        streetId: 2
    }
};

var fields = ["id", "name", "address.streetName"];

for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
    var value = getProperty(data, fields[i]);
    console.log(fields[i] + "=" + value);
}
```

**Output:**

```
id=1
name=abc
address.streetName=cde
```

Comment: Thanks Michael ..this is what I am doing..just wondering if there could be more efficient way of doing that..

Comment: Just realized I was doing unnecessary eval after constructing data["address"]["streetName"] using for loop. I think your's answer is most efficient. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This is a function I use to find data in nested objects:

```
Object.prototype.find = function() {
  try {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).reduce(function(acc, key) {
      return acc[key]
    }, this)
  }
  catch(e) {
    return 
  }
}
```

Data structure:

```
data = {
  "id":1,
  "name":"abc",
  "address": {
    "streetName":"cde",
    "streetId":2
  }
}
```

Function call:

```
data.find("address","streetName")
```

Returns:

```
"cde"
```