# How to set a valueKey for typeahead.js that points to a nested object property?

Tags: typeahead.js

Say, I have a json file

```
[{"id":1,"color":"green","user":{"id":3,"email":"example@gmail.com","name":"Bob Dylan"}}]
```

and I'm initializing typeahead.js object where I want "valueKey" property to point to a property "name" of a nested object "user" of the above json.

```
$('#dom-object-id').typeahead([
    {
        name: 'someName',
        prefetch: {
            url: '../assets/template/data/fromAbove.json', 
            ttl: 1
        },
        valueKey: "user.name", // this obviously doesn't work
        template: [
            '<p>{{user.name}}</p>',
        ].join(''),
        engine: Hogan
    }
]);
```

Any ideas if it's possible to do that without changing the source code/overriding internal typeahead.js methods (actually overriding would be fine as well)?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure you can do that, but you *can* use a `filter:` to process the JSON result and construct a new array of datums from it. In it, "promote" user.name to be a direct key of each item (say as the key `user_name`), and set `valueKey` to `user_name`.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I haven't tried your idea as I already used the one I posted. Nevertheless, I think yours should work. 
Downsides that I see: the solution is not replicable. For each case one would need to write a new filter or change existing one.
Upsides: no need to go into typeahead's source code.

Comment: `filter` is the correct way to achieve what you want. See https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/#prefetch

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found one way by changing the source code of typeahead (not the best one though).

I added a function after function _transformDatum:

```
_getProperty: function(json, path) {
    var tokens = path.split(".");
    var obj = json;
    for (var i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
        obj = obj[tokens[i]];
    }
    return obj;
}
```

that parses the string to get nested property (thanks to [How to access nested JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9463233/how-to-access-nested-json-data)) and changed _transformDatum function to:

```
_transformDatum: function(datum) {
    var value = utils.isString(datum) ? datum : this._getProperty(datum, this.valueKey), tokens = datum.tokens || utils.tokenizeText(value), item = {
        value: value,
        tokens: tokens
    };
    if (utils.isString(datum)) {
        item.datum = {};
        item.datum[this.valueKey] = datum;
    } else {
        item.datum = datum;
    }
    item.tokens = utils.filter(item.tokens, function(token) {
        return !utils.isBlankString(token);
    });
    item.tokens = utils.map(item.tokens, function(token) {
        return token.toLowerCase();
    });
        return item;
}
```

I still hope someone could find a solution without changing typeahead.js source code.