# How to read a complex and nested json data

Tags: javascript, json

My question is, how can you read a specefic form of json data using javascript, for example if i had this one, it's seems to me a bet difficult, so can you help me out.

```
{
  "jQRReponse": [
    [
      {
        "sujet": "RHONE ALPES",
        "verbe": "est_le_nom_de_la_region",
        "complement": {
          "sujet": "82",
          "verbe": "est_la_region_du_dept",
          "complement": {
            "sujet": "01",
            "verbe": "est_le_numero_du_dept",
            "complement": {
              "sujet": "Ain",
              "verbe": "contient_les_resultats_de_depAnn",
              "complement": {
                "sujet": "Ain2014",
                "verbe": "Pop_results_Ens_Total",
                "complement": "626794"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "sujet": "RHONE-ALPES",
        "verbe": "est_le_nom_de_la_region",
        "complement": {
          "sujet": "82",
          "verbe": "est_la_region_du_dept",
          "complement": {
            "sujet": "01",
            "verbe": "est_le_numero_du_dept",
            "complement": {
              "sujet": "Ain",
              "verbe": "contient_les_resultats_de_depAnn",
              "complement": {
                "sujet": "Ain2014",
                "verbe": "Pop_results_Ens_Total",
                "complement": "626794"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Say if I had this form:

```
data : [{
toto:5,
mama:10
},
{
toto:99,
mama:10
},
{
toto:88,
mama:10
}]
```

I'm gonna read the toto value at the index i like this : 
`data[i].toto`.

So how can I do it for the first one.

Thank you

Comment: which key value you want to read?

Comment: Acttually I want to be able to read all values that I can use them later

Comment: @YahyaAlami first you parse the data in the javascript to json object, you can visualise your data here   http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/   , then using  obj.jQRReponse[1].sujet  etc  , just a tip

Comment: well thank you @ARUN I will try this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access nested JSON data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9463233/how-to-access-nested-json-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate over all data and get the ressult.

The access is in the form like

```
data.jQRReponse[0][0].complement.complement.sujet
// returns "01"
```

```js
function read(o) {
    Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
        if (o[k] !== null && typeof o[k] === 'object') {
            console.log(k + ' -->');
            read(o[k]);
            return;
        }
        console.log(k + ': ' + o[k]);
    });
}

var data = { "jQRReponse": [[{ "sujet": "RHONE ALPES", "verbe": "est_le_nom_de_la_region", "complement": { "sujet": "82", "verbe": "est_la_region_du_dept", "complement": { "sujet": "01", "verbe": "est_le_numero_du_dept", "complement": { "sujet": "Ain", "verbe": "contient_les_resultats_de_depAnn", "complement": { "sujet": "Ain2014", "verbe": "Pop_results_Ens_Total", "complement": "626794" } } } } }], [{ "sujet": "RHONE-ALPES", "verbe": "est_le_nom_de_la_region", "complement": { "sujet": "82", "verbe": "est_la_region_du_dept", "complement": { "sujet": "01", "verbe": "est_le_numero_du_dept", "complement": { "sujet": "Ain", "verbe": "contient_les_resultats_de_depAnn", "complement": { "sujet": "Ain2014", "verbe": "Pop_results_Ens_Total", "complement": "626794" } } } } }]] };

read(data, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the specific part of this nested json object if you know the element, depth and the key.

Say if your element is 0, depth is 2 and the key is `verbe`, then you can do like this:

```
nestedObj[0].complement.complement.complement.verbe
```

If your requirement is to traverse the whole object and find something you need, you can use a recursive function for each element.

```
function traverse_it(obj){

    for(var prop in obj){

        console.log(obj[prop]);            //Or whatever you want to do with this level

        if(typeof obj[prop]=='object'){
           traverse_it(obj[prop[i]]);      //Function goes to the next level here

        }
    }
}

traverse_it(nestedObj);
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9463233/how-to-access-nested-json-data) is lot of insight

Comment: no that's incorrect it must be like this actually nestedObj[i][0], but I thank you tho for your answer

Comment: My answer considered only the obj part. Not the array which contained multitudes of it.

Comment: oh ok ! In this case I have no problems with it, thank's