# How do I get the name of the players and the data contained inside the players?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm new to Javascript and jQuery and I'm trying to make an in game scoreboard for Rocket League and ran into some trouble.

Here is the console log of `data` from the game:
[image: Console log of data from the game]

I'm trying to access the stats like `boost` contained inside the players, however, but I don't really want to change the player's names in the code every time to access it.

I was able to access the team scores by doing this

```js
$(".scorebug .team.left .score").text(d['game']['teams'][0]['score']);
```

but for the players, I tried doing something like

```js
$(".scorebug .playernames .playerBlue1").text(d['players'].child());
```

and

```js
$(".scorebug .playernames .playerBlue1").text(d['players'].next());
```

but it doesn't work.

Is there a way I can select `Buzz_2`, `Foamer_5`, `Heater_6`, `Outlaw_1`, `Sundown_3` and `Tex_7` without having to type their names in the code every time? Thanks!

Comment: Something like `[...data.games.players.keys()].map((player) => {console.log(player.boost)})` should work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access nested JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9463233/how-to-access-nested-json-data)

Comment: Thank you guys so much! I managed to get it working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to get the players stats in the order they appear in the data, you can simply loop through them with JavaScript's `for...in` loop.

What do you want to do with these scores? Do you want to log them to your console? Or do you want to save them to variables or an array for later use?

If you just want to log them, you could do something as simple as

```
for (let player in data.players) {
    let playerBoostStat = data.players[player].boost
    console.log(player + ' has a boost of ' + playerBoostStat)
}
```

That will log a sentence exclaiming each player's name and respective boost stat.

Comment: Thank you so much! I combined your answer with some of the comments above and I managed to get it working. Literally celebrating right now ahaha